# How to update multiple WPF UserControls asynchronously when an event occurs?

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have an event handler that is called from native code. I need to do some stuff there and then call asynchronously update for 4 different UserControls. The idea is that the event handler can proceed so that other stuff on native side can be done. My 1st try was like:

```
interface ISelectedObjectDependent
{
    void SelectedObjectsChanged();
}

public void ObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is important stuff that UserControl update methods 
    // need to access
    _selectedObjectIds.Clear();
    _updateIds = true;
    Count = Interface.UI.SelectedObjects.Count;
    ObjectProperties.Instance.AttributeObject = Count == 1
            ? Interface.UI.SelectedObjects.Get().FirstOrDefault()
            : null;

    foreach (var vm in MyApp.ViewModels)
    {
        if (vm.Value is ISelectedObjectDependent)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Action)(() =>
            {
                ((ISelectedObjectDependent) vm.Value).SelectedObjectsChanged();
            }));
        }
    }
 }
```

The ViewModels that implement ISelectedObjectDependent have the method implementations like this:

```
    public void SelectedObjectsChanged()
    {
        // do some stuff
        // ....
        // refresh datagrid
        ContractsItemsSource.Refresh();
    }
```

My question is: Is there a better way to refresh the 4 UserControl content in terms of:

1. total execution time
2. total time of unresponsive UI
3. longest single period of unresponsive UI

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The UI will never be responsive during the time it takes for the Refresh() method(s) to execute.

Comment: yes, you are right. i edit the question. i experienced more unresponsiveness due to a test code that adds slowness for test purposes. this works as expected. i guess the question is: "Is there a better way to do this?"

Comment: A better way to do what exactly?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Why do you need to call Refresh?

Comment: do u mean ContractsItemsSource.Refresh(); ? that I must call because selected objects are changed -> datagrid content must change

Comment: But do you really need to refresh the entire DataGrid each time?

Comment: it has to be done each time because the content most likely changes entrirely

Comment: Then you are out of luck because you cannot re-render the DataGrid on any other thread.

Comment: i know. but it can be done in same UI thread other ways also. e.g. giving another DispatcherPriority, using Task and await, using async event handling ans so on.

Comment: You could pass a priority to the BeginInvoke method. But Task? No.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154778/discussion-between-matti-and-mm8).

Answer (score 1):

This my solution ONLY to limit the longest single unresponsive time and total unresponsive time. The problem was that multiple asychronous calls were dispatched and executed for nothing.

I start the asynchronous methods exactly the same, but i limit the number of asynchronous calls by tracking the calls. In addition i don't call at all if not necessary and i have order / priority for calls.

ISelectedObjectDependent.cs

```
interface ISelectedObjectDependent
{
    void SelectedObjectsChanged();
    int ExecutionOrder { get; }
    bool NeedsRefresh();
    int QueueCount { get; set; }
}
```

SelectedObjects.cs

```
    private List<ISelectedObjectDependent> _viewModels; 

    public void ObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        _selectedObjectIds.Clear();
        _updateIds = true;
        Count = Interface.UI.SelectedObjects.Count;
        ObjectProperties.Instance.SetAttributeObjectNoRefresh(Count == 1
            ? Interface.UI.SelectedObjects.Get().FirstOrDefault() : null);

        if (_viewModels == null)
        {
            _viewModels = new List<ISelectedObjectDependent>();

            _viewModels = MyApp.ViewModels.Where(vm => vm.Value is ISelectedObjectDependent).Select(vm => (ISelectedObjectDependent)vm.Value)
                .OrderBy(vm => vm.ExecutionOrder)
                .ToList();
        }
        foreach (var vm in _viewModels)
        {
            if (vm.NeedsRefresh() && vm.QueueCount < 1)
            {
                vm.QueueCount++;
                App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Action) (() =>
                {
                    vm.SelectedObjectsChanged();
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

ContractsViewModel.cs (one of 4 implementations)

```
public class ContractsViewModel : ViewModel, ISelectedObjectDependent
{
    // only Interface members shown here

    public int ExecutionOrder { get { return 4; } }

    public bool NeedsRefresh()
    {
        return _isVisible;
    }
    public int QueueCount { get; set; }

    public void SelectedObjectsChanged()
    {
        ContractsItemsSource.Refresh();
        RaisePropertyChanged("ContractCount");
        RaisePropertyChanged("InfoText");
        QueueCount--;
    }
}
```